# Why i get invert signal when pass through the mosfet

Tags: mosfet

I'm about using LT3092 circuit as my dc current controller. Firstly, i set the pulse from Arduino about 1kHz and directly connected to the mosfet VN2222L. I want the pulse as i set that should be rising but unfortunately when i measure signal of pulse at the drain leg of mosfet, the pulse is inverted. Please give any suggestion and your help are greatly appreciated. Thank you  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPHpc.png]

Answer (score 3):

When you apply a decent gate voltage to a MOSFET, it turns on to a low value resistance between drain and source hence, the voltage at the drain becomes very close to the voltage at the source. Given that the source is connected to 0 V, it follows that if you apply a decent gate voltage you will get a drain voltage that is close to 0 V and, when you apply 0 V to the gate, with an appropriate load between drain and positive power rail, the drain will rise to a high voltage that is limited by the power rail.

In other words, a common source configured MOSFET is a voltage inverter.

If you look at your picture in the question, "ON" at the gate signifies current flowing at the load and "off" at the gate signifies that load current is being diverted through the MOSFET and very little will reach the load.

None of that is contradictory.

Comment: Thanks for your favor. Then, that's mean i have to use the appropriate value of voltage. so, how can i want the voltage across the drain is still in positive.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Voltage has to be across (or between) two places i.e. between drain and source or point A and point B. You have to use the appropriate value of voltage on the gate to turn the MOSFET on and off, usually between 3 volts and 20 volts (device dependent).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VI plot of MOSFET with grounded source, and drain tied thru 100 ohm resistor to +10 volts. As the gate voltage increases above Vthreshold, the Drain voltage drops and drops, becoming closer to ZERO......inversion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWR3Bk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>